# Adding triangle in each link menu's bottom according to the width of the link

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am converting one psd menu to css based menu. Find original psd design below

[image: original psd design]

My work is followed without triangle .

my problem is add triangle according to width of the link
[image]

My html

```
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse menu pull-right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#">
                        Home
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                     ABOUT US
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                    PRODUCTS
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      Portfolio
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#features-listing">
                       HR Service
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#offers">
                      Contact
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css (help of bootstrap)

```
                .menu ul > li > a {
                padding: 63px 18px 31px;
                color: #000;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            .menu ul > li > a:hover {
                background: #2390D5;
                color: #fff !important;
            }
            .menu ul li a {
                transition: border 150ms ease-in-out 0s, background-color 150ms ease-in-out 0s;
            }
            .menu .active {
                background: #2390D5;
            }
            li.active a {
                color: #fff !important;
            }
```

Comment: As far as I know you can only use defined pixel values for borders on pseudo elements and % values will not work...so that's out. Perhaps SVG...hmm.

Comment: Pretty simple using borders.

Comment: Your HTML and CSS appears to be incomplete: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2E2s5/).

Comment: David. I added bootstrap resources a the CDN: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/GvHaD/1/

Comment: @lharby i seen your work. nice work. but its cut some below angle

Comment: @hserusv yeah I gave up on it, because I had to use px, and you need different sized triangles for the different list items according to the width of the content. My preference is actually to use an image. You will get some stretching. Or alternatively use a fixed width for each list item.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use borders to generate the triangle

```
<div class="arrow-down"></div>

.arrow-down {
    border-left: 24px solid transparent;
    border-right: 24px solid transparent;
    border-top: 24px solid #00f;
}
```

Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4m3qU/)

p.s I set all the widths of the links to be equal so to allow for it to work like this

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding a background image to your li elements? If the background contains a correct image and is set to stretch it should provide you with the output you want.

I hope you know what I mean by this :) 
I know it's sort of a hack, but if you don't come up with anything else this should work..

Comment: Background image is the way to go. I was trying to create triangles in pure css using content:after and borders, but you cannot use % measurements for these elements. There should be a way to do it using a js function, but that will involve more code.